# Restoring seemingly completely gone .java file

Tags: java, file

A while back I had a problem occur in Eclipse where somehow the main class of my game (written in LWJGL and Slick2D) was wiped, and replaced with just tab delimiters. Since then, I've been trying to rewrite the file, but the game just won't launch.

Is there any way I can restore the file? Things I've tried:

- Restoring from Eclipse's in-built system (empty)
- Restoring from Windows older files system (also empty)
- Looking for backups elsewhere
- Decompiling the .class files in the bin directory (already overwritten)

I'm completely stumped here. If there's no way to do this, I'll post another question asking why it's not working or perhaps just Google even **more** extensively.

Comment: Use a version control system?

Comment: I used a utility called [Restoration](http://download.cnet.com/Restoration/3000-2094_4-10322950.html) in the past to try to find deleted files, but it looks like Eclipse overwrote your file, so you're almost certainly not going to get it back. (I have no idea why this would happen to you, it's not like you were using Emacs or anything.)

Comment: @IsmailBadawi I'm now using GitHub, but when I lost the file I didn't think too far into it and didn't use anything like that. I was told Eclipse would have made its own backups.

Comment: It may be different in eclipse but in netbeans the runnable jar in the dist folder is only overwritten on a clean and build. If you haven't done one of those since then then the .class may still exist there (in the .jar)

Comment: @RichardTingle There is no dist folder using Eclipse, and in the bin folder the class has been overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't exited Eclipse you might be able to do a Replace with Local History.  Depends on what version of Eclipse you're using.  Unless that is what you meant by "Eclipse's inbuilt system."

Comment: This was almost a month ago now, I've closed and opened Eclipse many times.

Comment: Sorry then.  I have no other ideas.